# python for loops being started at 1st element no 0th element

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, pycharm

I am writing a simple text-based RPG battle simulator using Python (running on PyCharm). I created a class called Person which has initialization parameters as follows:

```
def __init__(self, name, HP, MP, ATK, DEF, magic, items):
    self.name = name
    self.HP = HP
    etc...
```

this class gets instantiated 3 times in `main` for 3 unique players (`player1, player2, player3`). I also have a function `get_stats(self)` which does

```
print(self.name + ", HP: " + self.HP + ", MP: " + self.MP)
```

but when I run in `main`

```
for player in players:
    player.get_stats()
```

where `players = {player1, player2, player3}`, I get the output (note that the MP/HP values are arbitrary):

```
name2, HP: 200, MP: 200
name3, HP: 300, MP: 300
name1, HP: 100, MP: 100
```

and if `players = {player0, player1, player2, player3}`, I get the output :

```
name2, HP: 200, MP: 200
name3, HP: 300, MP: 300
name0, HP: 400, MP: 400
name1, HP: 100, MP: 100
```

why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sets are not ordered.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/zyxtheros/Python_Projects/blob/c38cc99548a3ec5a21b11f252db0d61fa5ede539/RPG_Battle/main.py) full code transcript for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` creates a `set` in python, which are not ordered: the elements are not stored in the way they are entered.

You need a list, which can be created as:

```
players = [player1, player2, player3]
```

or a tuple:

```
players = (player1, player2, player3)
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much! A hangup from my time using C/C++

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `{}` syntax that is meant for `set`s in Python. Sets do not have an order, and will yield their members at random when used in a `for` statement.

Simply be consistent and use `(Player0, ...)` to denote a tuple, or `[Player0, ...]`  to denote a list - both of these types are "sequences", which have a well defined order.